# nested this is pointing to the wrong variable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the class below

The `this` in `new SeatReservation("Steve", this.availableMeals[0]),` is refering to inside `seats` , How do I make it refer to the correct one `availableMeals`

Can I go `new SeatReservation("Steve", parent.this.availableMeals[0]),`

```
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    //var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    this.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    this.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", this.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", this.availableMeals[0])
    ]);

    // Operations
    this.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", this.availableMeals[0]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. You just need to learn how `this` works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `self` variable you commented out

```
self.availableMeals[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work with `this` too, because you didn't switch context. Maybe there is something wrong with the binding in the HTML. I created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ay4n/) which may hopefully help you out.

EDIT: Ahh, if you mean the statement within `addSeat`, you really need the `self` variable, or you apply the correct object as `this`:

```
this.addSeat = function() {
    this.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", this.availableMeals[0]));
}.apply(this);
```